# Detect the end of a HTTP packet

Tags: php, http, sockets

I have to write a PHP script that works as a client against another HTTP Server. This Server ignores the HTTP Connection:Close header and keeps the TCP connection open unless it is closed by the client. And here is my dilemma. I (the client) have to deciede when a HTTP request/response has finished and then close the connection. Simply use:

> $data = file_get_contents($url);

.. won't work, as file_get_contents returns only if the connection timeout (default 30 seconds) has reached.

So I have to write my own read - loop like this (pseudo code):

```
$sock = fsockopen(...);
$data = '';
while($line = fgets($sock)) {
    $data .= $line;
    if(http_package_recieved()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is no Content-Length header in the response. My question is, how the function

`http_package_recieved()`

... should look like.

Greets 
Thorsten

Comment: The question was downvoted today - 5 years after having posted. Can the downvoter explain the reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't close the connection **and** it doesn't tell you the total length of the response, you have no way to know whether all the data has been received.

You could specify a maximum time interval between packets, but that won't be reliable.

Comment: You can, if it's using HTTP Chunked Transfer Encoding.

Comment: @Bruno That's true. It remains to be seen if that's the case (the OP doesn't specify it).

Comment: @Bruno: That's a big *if*. However, unless the server specifies this or Content-length and doesn't close the connection, there's indeed no way to tell (shouldn't happen, but apparently can).

Comment: I'll read about Transfer-Encoding: chunked and tell my success (or not ;) )

Answer (score 3):

You can check if $line is empty to see if the server isn't sending anything. You can also set a small read timeout on the socket with `stream_set_timeout()` , and then inside the loop check `stream_get_meta_data()` to see if it has been reached in order to break out.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better of using a library, such as cURL (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php), to handle this. The HTTP spec isn't simple: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616 (see Section 4.4) and you'd likely miss something crucial.

Answer (score 1):

When the entity ends is either guided by:

- `Content-Length` header (which you don't have)
- [HTTP Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (see `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header: do you have one of these?).

It's possible you may have to process this chunked transfer encoding if you get this header. There are libraries to do so.

Comment: Transfer-Encoding: chunked, I *have*. I'll read about this. thanks.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a library to do so, unless you have a good reason not to. libcurl is available via PHP (as @Rushyo said).

Answer (score 0):

`feof($sock)` would be OK