# An easy way to detect the end of http response (raw socket, java)?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to retrieve the server's response as is, with all headers. The first thing that comes to mind is to use raw sockets. As I have learned from the search, there are 3 ways to indicate the end of response:

(1) closing the connection;

  (2) examining `Content-Length`;

  (3) getting all chunks in the case of `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked`.

  There is also

  (4) the timeout method: assume that the timeout means end of data, but the latter is not really reliable.

I want a general-case solution and do not want to

 add a `Connection: close` line to the request itself.

In addition, it is recommended to use an existing library rather than re-invent the wheel.

**Question:**

***How do I use an existing package, preferably, something already present in Android, to detect the end of HTTP response while having access (without interference) to the raw data stream?***

UPD: forgot to mention that the HTTP request is given to me as a sequence of bytes. Yes, it is for testing.

PS

 relevant reading:

 [End of an HTTP Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515565/end-of-an-http-response)

 [Detect the end of an HTTP Request in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384508/detect-the-end-of-an-http-request-in-java)

 [Detect end of HTTP request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824451/detect-end-of-http-request-body)

 [How HTTP Server inform its clients that the response has ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689684/how-http-server-inform-its-clients-that-the-response-has-ended)

 [Proper handling of chuncked Http Response within Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456303/proper-handling-of-chuncked-http-response-within-socket)

 [Detect the end of a HTTP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718158/detect-the-end-of-a-http-packet)

 [Android socket & HTTP response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648551/android-socket-http-response-headers?rq=1)

 [Java HTTP GET response waits until timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527291/java-http-get-response-waits-until-timeout)

Comment: "*... way to detect the end of http response*": The answers should all be in here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230 (chapters 3.2 and 3.3)

Comment: @alk are you crazy?  who would read RFCs ;-)

Comment: Such nitpickers like me ...? ;-) @pskink Also I feel it's worth mentioning that the http related RFCs had been rewritten. Clarifying lots of ambiguities ..

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to use HttpURLConnection, in which the problem is already solved. You just read the input stream until end of stream. It takes care of when that should happen.

Comment: @alk you are the exception, i bet that 50% of folks here even don't know that such a thing like RFC even exists....

Comment: @alk I do not have enough resources to debug and then test code written from scratch up to RFC. In addition, in real life there always are gotchas (e.g. servers reject queries if the user-agent is not "Mozilla"), and I do not have time to learn them all the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a the Apache HTTP client package (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ ) so you don't need to implement all the finicky details of the HTTP protocol.

The Apache Http Client will give you access to the headers and their content, which may be enough for you.

If you really need access to the actual character sequence sent by the server (e.g. for debugging purposes), you could then intercept the communication by replacing the connection socket factory with your own to create "intercepting" sockets which store all data transferred in a buffer where your code can access it later on. See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e418